# How to migrate pyorc.Reader(data, struct_repr=StructRepr.DICT) to pyarrow.orc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarrow, orc

I was using pyorc(0.7.0) to read orc files and it was working fine, recently when I tried to run the same in my local I started getting the below error

```
Python(84489,0x7ff84e9ea680) malloc: *** error for object 0x6000008f85a8: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(84489,0x7ff84e9ea680) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I didn't get much help around it, so I migrated to another library pyarrow.orc, I was able to read the orc file with pyarrow but it didn't provide same functionality as pyorc.
Also I needed to read data row wise, but pyarrow methods are more inclined towards columns-wise read.

below is the raw data from orc file, test.orc

```
{
"update_time": "2020-07-04:23:18:02.178584000",
"id": "0BZI0XHLL0N3B",
"etl_load_date": "2020-07-05 00:46:57.828",
"end_date": "9999-12-31 00:00:00.0",
"errormapcol": [{"_key": "Status", "_value": "Pass"}],
"source_file_name_dl": "part=2020-07-04.txt",
}
```

pyorc was able to read metadata as well and convert if necesarry, with pyorc I was fetching a row as below

```
with open(path_to_file, "rb") as data:
    rows = pyorc.Reader(data, struct_repr=StructRepr.DICT)
    for row in rows:
        yield row
```

I was getting below response

```
"update_time": "2020-07-04:23:18:02.178584000",
"instance_id": "0BZI0XHLL0N3B",
"etl_load_date": datetime(2020, 7, 5, 0, 46, 57, 828000, tzinfo=timezone.utc),
"end_date": datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc),
"errormapcol": {"Status": "Pass"},
"source_file_name_dl": "part=2020-07-04.txt",
```

pyorc was able to read column errormapcol and convert its value into dict, but when I switched to pyarrow I got the errormapcol values as list, alongwith etl_load_date and end_date as Timestamp. Below is the response when I read via pyarrow

```
'errormapcol': [('Status', 'Pass')],
'end_date': Timestamp('1816-03-29 05:56:08.066277376'),
'etl_load_date': Timestamp('2020-07-05 00:46:57.828000'),
```

I used below approches with pyarrow

```
import pyarrow.orc as orc

  with open(path_to_file, "rb") as data:
            table  = orc.read_table(data)
            rows = table.to_pandas()
            for _, row in rows.iterrows():
                row_dict = row.to_dict()
                yield row
```

Also tried

```
import pyarrow.orc as orc

with open(path_to_file, "rb") as data:
            table  = orc.read_table(data)
            rows = table.to_pylist()
            for row in rows:
                yield row
```

But got the same result from both approcahes.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or do I need to switch to some other library, thanks.